# Spring Web Socket not broadcasting message to all application servers

Tags: grails, load-balancing, spring-websocket

I am trying to setup load balanced environment having 2 application server instances. I am unable to make spring web socket relay messages to all instances. Let's take a example to describe my problem better:

- Server 1 : Responsible for job executions and 35% user load.
- Server 2 : 100% user load.

Both are connected to same database schema so job request can come for any server instance but will get executed on Server 1.

Now, I have used spring web socket plugin for my GRAILS application and I push messages to browser using

```
brokerMessagingTemplate.convertAndSend(user.notificationChannel, ((notification.toMap(user) as JSON)).toString())
```

It was working fine on single server setup. But on multi-server setup,
notifications are only received on Server 1 as that is the one calling the code block, if reverse the scenario, then vice-versa result is observed.

How can I push same notification to all server instances, so that user always gets the notification no matter what server instance he is on?

I initially thought of utilising a common queue like RabitMQ but that will add to system requirements and will get disapproved by client.

NOTE: Third party service solutions won't work in my case as applications are on intranet and don't have internet access.

Comment: From what I understand of it all, you can't achieve this the way you are going about it. Websockets are bound to your sessions created locally on the server, this is the reason it is not working on multiple servers, each server has its own sessions and users connected to it. You could create a 2nd app that the users would connect through either through REST auth or however it is - maybe no auth just their username sufficient.. 2nd app connected through a taglib that resonds to all users regardless of server/app. take a look at wschat plugin on how socket connections triggered via taglib

Comment: Thinking more about this, again same plugin uses websocket client,boselecta plugin uses extensively a `websocket client` that runs as part of the application, rather than message end users, you would message the websocket client - which would be running on all the instances, the websocket client would then attempt to look up the user locally on each machine if found to broadcast - the user at this point would be a real springsecurity user or whatever that got passed to the cient - that is possibly your best option

Comment: @Vahid please answer the question, I ended up using Hazelcast publisher to publish messages to every server, and as suggested by you. my only option was to create spring websocket connections per browser tab. 
Whenever my server received messages from Hazelcast, I published to all spring websocket session created by application locally on each server for that user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

websockets by default point to a hostname/ip address - whilst you could setup a dns record / hostname that points to multiple different ip's /  servers. This itself would break communication flow of the websockets if it sent handshake to one and the message to another.

The most simplest approach would be to think of some db table that is shared across both and as each instance comes up/alive it records its local ip / socket port to a db table - each instance can then read this table and work out at any point which are the hosts to transmit a socket message to -  (this table would need to managed somehow - upon a brand new bootup ) it would be empty and would popuplate as instances came up - something again to manage when a host is taken down shutdown.

Each instance would then be running an [ws internal client](https://github.com/vahidhedayati/grails-wschat-plugin/blob/master/src/main/groovy/grails/plugin/wschat/client/WsChatClientEndpoint.groovy). When a message is sent the ws client would be triggered attempting to find all alive websocket servers "from the db" to each using the [ws client](https://github.com/vahidhedayati/grails-wschat-plugin/blob/1698a6eaca51b50a4f5fb42d35e68ebb6228aa49/grails-app/services/grails/plugin/wschat/client/ChatClientListenerService.groovy#L110) it would attempt to connect and send the message on. Each would then get the message and either broadcast to all connected users or if it is from user x meant for user x then like per chat plugin it would relay it only to user x if found on server y and so on.

this then keeps it all inline with 1 technology controlling the entire process websocket server that has its own client which relay to the end multiple instance ws socket server

Comment: Just to point out : We can utilize Hazelcast for backend logic, as it would take care of all data replication, and sending data to every instance.